# Was the Mexican Congress shown corpses of extra-terrestrials?

Tags: aliens

According to [The Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/aliens-in-mexico-congress-ufo-b2410477.html), journalist and Ufologist, [Jaime Maussan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaime_Maussan) testified to a Mexican congressional hearing that apparent mummified/fossilized corpses are extra-terrestrials: they are not part of "our terrestrial evolution".

> Mr Maussan told attendees the specimens had been studied by scientists at the Autonomous National University of Mexico (UNAM) who were able to draw DNA evidence using radiocarbon dating. After comparisons were made to other DNA samples, it was found that over 30% of the specimens’ DNA was “unknown”, he said.

A video of the testimony was [released by the Mexican Congress](https://youtu.be/AiXnkTgBem4?t=8951).

Are these mummies/fossils of extra-terrestrials?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148528/discussion-on-question-by-curiousindeed-was-the-mexican-congress-shown-corpses-o); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Please, no more comments sharing opinions without evidence. Take that to chat.

Comment: https://www.snopes.com/news/2023/09/13/alien-corpses-mexican-congress/